# How to open online word documents with DevExpress in an ASP.NET Core Web Application, Framework .NET6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Could someone help me with an ASP.NET Core (MVC) web application choosing .NET Framework 6 I want to open Word documents hosted in the cloud with DevExpress Rich Edit, I know what that is, but I can't get it to work. Currently it only opens documents locally.

This is the repo:
https://github.com/JesusPerezIMD/document-viewer-app.RichEdit